# How to make null comparison to return false

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this

```
xml1Element = xml1.Elements().SingleOrDefault(
                            e =>
                                String.Equals(
                                    (string)e.Attribute("boo"),
                                    (string)xml2Element.Attribute("boo"))
```

So, `(string)xml2Element.Attribute("boo")` returns `null`, as well as all other `(string)e.Attribute("boo")`. And since `null==null` returns `true`, I receive exception:

> Sequence contains more than one matching element

How to make `null==null` to return `false` instead? So that `String.Equals(null,null)` is `false`.

Comment: O.o  `!string.Equals(null,null);`

Comment: You want to make null not equal null?  Just negate the expression?

Comment: @TraeMoore I think OP does not really want to compare null with null, but the xml-attributes, which may or may not be `null`.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What you actually want to do is check both return values for null first, not change the nature of `String.Equals` because your code doesn't work...

Comment: I don't want always to retrovert that. Sometimes those are not null, and I want to treat them as usual. I only want to do opposite of null,null situation

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I was scratching my head forsure... +1 on your answer

Comment: Thanks for quick help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can´t. But you can just add the null-check before by using an anonymous method:

```
xml1Element = xml1.Elements().SingleOrDefault(e => {
                            var a = (string)e.Attribute("boo");
                            var b = (string)xml2Element.Attribute("boo"));
                            if(a == null && b == null) return false;
                            return String.Equals(a, b);
                        });
```

As an asside `(string)xml2Element.Attribute("boo")` allways returns the same value. Querying it again and again is probably meaningless and lowers your performance. Just extract that outside your query.

Comment: "boo" is variable actually, I just simplified in post to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude nulls:

```
xml1Element = xml1.Elements().SingleOrDefault(
    e =>
        e.Attribute("boo") != null &&
        String.Equals(
            (string)e.Attribute("boo"),
            (string)xml2Element.Attribute("boo"));
```

You need to test only one attribute for `null`. Because, if the other one is null, we want to return `false` and if the other one is not null, then they are not equal and we return false as well. If the first one is not null but the other one is, then they are not equal as well and we return false.